# Following CROSS JOIN how to remove records comparing same record

Tags: cross-join

I have done a CROSS JOIN, comparing each record to all other records.

However, I want to remove those where the same record is being compared.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide some query text or example of the SQL you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
CROSS JOIN Table2
WHERE Table1.PrimaryKey <> Table2.PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if you are looking to remove the records from both tables whenever there are duplicates, but here is how I would do it.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA
(
    PK_A INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Field1 INT,
    Field2 VARCHAR(20),
    Field3 BIT
)
INSERT INTO #TableA (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES (1, 'A', 0), (1, 'B', 1), (2, 'C', 1), (3, 'C', 0)

CREATE TABLE #TableB
(
    PK_B INT IDENTITY(10,10) NOT NULL,
    Field1 INT,
    Field2 VARCHAR(20),
    Field3 BIT
)
INSERT INTO #TableB (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES (1, 'A', 1), (1, 'B', 1), (2, 'C', 1), (3, 'C', 1)

SELECT * FROM #TableA;
SELECT * FROM #TableB;

DECLARE @pks AS TABLE 
(
    PK_A INT,
    PK_B INT
)

INSERT INTO @pks (PK_A, PK_B)
SELECT PK_A, PK_B 
FROM #TableA INNER JOIN #TableB
ON #TableA.Field1 = #TableB.Field1
    AND #TableA.Field2 = #TableB.Field2
    AND #TableA.Field3 = #TableB.Field3

DELETE FROM #TableA WHERE PK_A IN (SELECT PK_A FROM @pks)
DELETE FROM #TableB WHERE PK_B IN (SELECT PK_B FROM @pks)

SELECT * FROM #TableA;
SELECT * FROM #TableB;

DROP TABLE #TableA;
DROP TABLE #TableB;
```